# Taking Value from one array with keys aret the valuses of another another array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array called `$stocknumb`

```
$stocknumb= Array ( [0] => 102 [1] => 103 [2] => 104 )
```

Another array called $price it contains both `$stocknumb` as well as price

```
$price=Array ( ['102'] => Array ( [0] => 2000 ) ['103'] => Array ( [0] => 3 ) ['104'] => Array ( [0] => 4000 ) )
```

Now i would like to get prices for only stock numbers which are in `$stocknumb` array. Both price and stock number are in `$price` array.

How to get it in PHP.

Comment: Don't Comment i open another question for my requirement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934402/send-me-solution-for-my-requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach($price as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($key, $stocknumb)) {
        echo $value[0];
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/86008)

Comment: @Karthipers i have added a working example in answer.

Answer (score 0):

See array_column function (php >= 5.5) :

```
$price= array(
  102 => array(0 => 2000),
  103 => array(0 => 3),
  104 => array(0 => 4000)
);
$array_price = array_column ($price, 0);

print_r($array_price);
/*Array
(
    [0] => 2000
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4000
)
*/
```

If you don't use php 5.5, see :
https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php

Comment: better i shall explain my case. I can't use your answers on my requirement. I thank you for your valuable time for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want final data as array then with conventional way of looping could be done as

```
$stocknumb= Array ( 0 => 102, 1 => 103, 2 => 104 )  ;
$price=Array ( '102' => Array ( 0 => 2000 ), '103' => Array ( 0 => 3 ), '104' => Array ( 0 => 4000 ) );

$final_array = array() ;
foreach($stocknumb as $key=>$val){
    if(array_key_exists($val,$price)){
        $final_array[$val] = $price[$val][0];
    }
}

print_r($final_array);
```

Output

```
Array ( [102] => 2000 [103] => 3 [104] => 4000 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array intersect function

```
$stocknumb= array ( 102, 103 );
// Make the key same as the value.
$stocknumb = array_combine($stocknumb, $stocknumb);

$price= array (102 => array (2000), 103 => array (3), 104 => array (4000 ));

$filtered = array_intersect_key($price, $stocknumb);
```

Answer (score 0):

### A single line of code with `array_flip()` and `array_key_intersect()` will suffice

```
$new_arr=array_intersect_key($price, array_flip($stocknumb));
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [102] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2000
        )

    [103] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

    [104] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4000
        )

)
```